# cgroup V1 setup does not work in cgroup V2

Tags: linux, ubuntu, memory, cgroup

I  have a cgroup setup that I use to limit memory usage for rsync and firefox, primarily. It is a manual setup (no systemd involvement) that I run from a Makefile after each boot (yeah I know not great, but systemd is such a hassle to learn).

When I upgraded from ubuntu 21.04 to 22.04 today, the law of unintended consequences ensured that my cgroup setup no longer works, probably because cgroup V2 is now standard.

What it looks like to me is that the file hierarchy in /sys/fs/cgroups has changed. I used to have, for example for my user reik

/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/custom/reik-2048M

which I created with a Makefile snippet that generates the following script

```
MEM=2048M
sudo cgcreate -a reik -t reik -g memory:/custom/reik-$(MEM)
sudo cgset -r memory.limit_in_bytes=$(MEM) custom/reik-$(MEM)
sudo cgset -r memory.memsw.limit_in_bytes=$(MEM) custom/reik-$(MEM)
```

I could then run a program  as follows

% gexec --sticky -g memory:custom/reik-2048M someprogram

With cgroup v2 the memory.blah variable names had changed, which I think I fixed, as follows

```
sudo cgcreate -a reik -t reik -g memory:/custom/reik-2048M
sudo cgset -r memory.max=2048M custom/reik-2048M
sudo cgset -r memory.swap.max=2048M custom/reik-2048M
```

But now I get an error if I try to run any program, say ls, as follows

```
% cgexec --sticky -g memory:custom/reik-2048M ls
cgroup change of group failed
```

One thing that seems different is that the file hierarchy no longer has the /memory/ component in it, that is, the path that gets created is just

/sys/fs/cgroup/custom/reik-2048M

That is as far as I got. I am looking for ideas on what I am doing wrong here. I also looked for docs about how to translate cgroup v1 commands into cgroup v2, but did not find anything very concrete.

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr:

```
systemd-run --user -G -P -d -p MemoryMax=2G -p MemorySwapMax=2G ls
```

This will create a .service on the fly, with the specified settings and command. (For .service units the same settings would go into the [Service] section.) The `--user` makes it run under your own service manager rather than the system-wide one.

A predefined cgroup can be created as `~/.config/systemd/user/foo.slice` and used via `--slice` with systemd-run (or `Slice=` in real .service units):

```
[Slice]
MemoryMax=2G
MemorySwapMax=2G

# systemd-run --user --collect --slice=foo.slice --pty --shell
```

(Note about systemd's slice naming: Dashes are hierarchy separators, i.e. `foo-bar.slice` is a child of `foo.slice`.)

> What it looks like to me is that the file hierarchy in /sys/fs/cgroups has changed. […] One thing that seems different is that the file hierarchy no longer has the /memory/ component in it, that is, the path that gets created is just

Yes, that's a big part of why it's cgroups "v2". The new cgroups system does not have individual per-controller trees anymore – there's only a single tree for everything, with subtrees having specific controllers enabled via their `cgroup.controller` files (cgcreate does this automatically).

In my tests, however, `CGROUP_LOGLEVEL=debug` says that the error message is because kernel doesn't allow the PID to be moved into the new cgroup. I'm not 100% sure as to why, but most likely the reason is that you're failing the "should be authorized to migrate to the common ancestor" rule in cgroup.c – the only common ancestor in this case is the root `/` cgroup, which you have no permissions for.

(systemd-run doesn't exec the process directly – instead it asks the `systemd --user` process to execute it, so both the source and destination cgroups are under the `[...]/user@1000.service` common ancestor which *is* owned by your UID and therefore passes the migration check.)

---

This leads to another difference worth mentioning – in the v2 model, a cgroup can either have tasks *or* subgroups but not both at once, so you couldn't *actually* move any processes into an ancestor cgroup; the previous paragraph uses "authorized to migrate" strictly in the sense of having write permissions to the common ancestor's `cgroup.procs`.

Comment: This looks like very useful starting point for me to get something working again. Thanks much! I think I will try to create a slice called 2048M.slice , and run all rsync commands in that slice., the goal being that any and all rsync processes are mutually (cumulatively) limited to 2048M max memory usage. Of course I will now have to reboot my machine without the systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=0 kernel setting that I used (in desperation last night) to disable cgroup V2 and bring back V1.

Comment: Overall I'm rather disappointed with the cgroup V2 documentation out there. I searched high and low for something along the line of "cgroup V2 for those who know cgroup V1", but came up empty. There is endless docs and 40 pages of slides about how V2 is so much better than V1, but nothing about how one actually uses it for a concrete need. (sorry I just had to let off a little steam on this topic. It  was very frustrating).

Comment: I would mark this answer as most helpful but I have not had time to change my setup to V2 since last time, so I have not tried it.  It will happen eventually, I hope, but right now I cannot afford the disruption.